# Vaadin and Node.js version

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

What is the minimum version for latest Vaadin Flow(23.3.1)?
On the host where jenkins is located, the old operating system and running node -v results is:

```
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.12.1-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.12.1-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.12.1-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.12.1-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.12.1-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
```

Is it possible to stay on version 16x?

Thanks

Comment: NodeJS 16 is the minimal requirement for 23.3

Comment: Do you need node js in production?

Comment: @AndréSchild No, only in build server(jenkins)

Comment: @Knoobie Why mvn clean install download 18x node js ?

Comment: Because it's the default if Vaadin could not find a proper installed nodejs available on your system.

Comment: Yes, you are right - by installing nodejs 16x in the OS, the build does not download nodejs 18x. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Vaadin 23.3, the minimum Node version is 16.14. You can find this information from the Vaadin Platform release notes; in the case of 23.3, here: https://github.com/vaadin/platform/releases/tag/23.0.0. The release notes also list other supported technologies, such as browser versions.

Answer (score 0):

For Vaadin 23.3, it's actually Node 16.15. See https://github.com/vaadin/platform/releases/tag/23.3.0.